How to use molecular sieve to remove water
I'm trying to make relatively pure hydrogen via electrolysis of water, but the reaction creates heat and there is a significant amount of water vapor mixed with my hydrogen.  Attempts to reduce this with cooling apparatus on the output side have proven messy and consume more power than the electrolysis.
I'd like to try filtering it with some sort of filtering apparatus that lets tiny hydrogen molecules to pass, and blocks water vapor.  Is a molecular sieve appropriate for this, and if so, how can I use it?

Standard activated moelcular sieves should do this https://brownell.co.uk/products/desiccants/molecular-sieves.html

As for saving energy using cooling to condense water, use countercurrent heat exchange: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countercurrent_exchange . The cold H2 exiting the condenser cools the warm H2 entering. For large quantities of H2, a cold trap would likely be the first step, followed by absorption near point of use.

Molecular sieve would work for this, yes.  You may also find that just plain silica gel also works.  Molecular sieves are generally more effective at higher temperatures.
It acts as a dessicant, however, and does not work as a "filter" in the way you seem to have described.
